# Integration of MAX30100 and DS18B20 Thermal Probe Integration

Tags: arduino-mega, sensors, code-review, project, project-critique

This is for my final year project that I have been tasked with designing a patient monitoring system. However, during the last stretch of model prototyping, I am experiencing issues with my MAX30100 and DS18B20 thermal probe.

My thermal probe is giving me a proper reading of the temperature. However, the oximeter values are always stuck to zero and the call back function is not executed. I did read that it was an issue where the thermal probe continues to do conversion and doesn't allow the max30100 sensor to perform any other functions. So for that, i just had to pass `sensors.setWaitForConversion(false);`

I did try to write the code for the DS18B20 thermal probe and the oximeter sensor seperately and it executed perfectly. However, when I try to integrate everything together into a final project, the max30100 sensor doesn't carry out the reading and is stuck to zero while the thermal probe is perfectly working finding out its temperature. I did the same coding process as the previous when i tried to seperately work with the thermal and oximeter sensor. However, it is the final integration that is causing a lot of issues.

The data will be sent to firebase real-time database via the ESP8266 Wi-Fi module. I have got it to work fine. But i am stuck on the final integration of the BP machine, the MAX30100 Oximeter sensor and the DS18B20 Waterproof Thermal Probe. I am also using the Arduino Mega2560 board.

Could anyone guide me as to how do I perform integration of the MAX30100 Sensor with the DS18B20 Probe?

Attaching code for my project below:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include "MAX30100_PulseOximeter.h"

#define REPORTING_PERIOD_MS 1000
PulseOximeter pox;
uint32_t tsLastReport = 0;
float oxy_lvl = 0.00;

unsigned char alert = 0;
unsigned char system_alert = 0;
unsigned char alert_flag=0;

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,16,2);
SoftwareSerial myserial(13, 12);    // RX, TX for blood pressure sensor
SoftwareSerial esp8266(3, 2);     // rx,tx for esp8266

#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 3
#define HELP_TONE buzz, 2000, 200

const int buzz=9;

OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);
float cel=0.00;

String data_pressure;
char  buff[15];

String send_data_string;

const int no_of_data = 5;
String main_data[10];
int sensorValue = 0;
unsigned int tempVal = 0; 

int  sys_u = 130, dia_u = 90, temp_l = 24, temp_u = 37, pulse_l = 30, pulse_u = 120;
int sys, dia, p, stay = 1;

void onBeatDetected()
{
  Serial.println("Heart beat detected!! Oximeter pulse detected!!");
}

void setup() 
{
  pinMode(buzz, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  esp8266.begin(9600);
  myserial.begin(9600);
  sensors.begin();
  sensors.setWaitForConversion(false);
  lcd.begin();
  lcd.clear();
  Serial.print("Initializing Oximeter and other sensors");
  if(!pox.begin())
  {
    Serial.println("Oximeter Failed");
    lcd.print("Oximeter Failed");
    for(;;);
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Oximeter Succeeded");
  }
  //pox.setIRLedCurrent(MAX30100_LED_CURR_7_6MA);
  pox.setOnBeatDetectedCallback(onBeatDetected);
  lcd.print(F("        Patient "));
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(F(" Health  Monitor "));
  delay(2000);  
  send_data_string = String(sys) + ',' + String(dia) + ',' + String(p) + ',' + String(cel) + ',' + String(oxy_lvl);
  Serial.println("send_data_string = " + String(send_data_string)); 
  send_parameters();  
  delay(4000);  
  lcd.clear();
}

void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(buzz,LOW);
  read_temperature_and_oxi();
  main_display();
   myserial.listen();
   if (myserial.available())
   {
     while (myserial.available())
     {
       data_pressure = myserial.readString();
     }
     data_pressure.trim();
     data_pressure.toCharArray(buff, data_pressure.length() + 1);
     if (sscanf(buff, "%d,%d,%d", &sys, &dia, &p) == 3)
     {
       lcd.clear();
       lcd.print(F("sys | dia | puls"));
       lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
       lcd.print(sys);
       lcd.setCursor(7, 1);
       lcd.print(dia);
       lcd.setCursor(12, 1);
       lcd.print(p);
       delay(7500);
       read_temperature_and_oxi();
       process();
       alerting();
       delay(500);
       send_data_string = String(sys) + ',' + String(dia) + ',' + String(p) + ',' + String(cel) + ',' + String(oxy_lvl);
       Serial.println("send_data_string = " + String(send_data_string)); 
       send_parameters();
       delay(3000);      
     } 
     myserial.end();    
   }  
   myserial.listen();
   delay(1);
}

void read_temperature_and_oxi()
{
  float HeartRate = 3.0, SpO2 = 3.0;
  pox.update();
  HeartRate = pox.getHeartRate();
  SpO2 = pox.getSpO2();
  //oxy_lvl=SpO2;
  if(millis() - tsLastReport > REPORTING_PERIOD_MS)
  {
    Serial.print("Heart Rate: ");
    Serial.print(HeartRate);
    Serial.print("bpm / SpO2: ");
    Serial.print(SpO2);
    Serial.println(" % ");
    
    sensors.requestTemperatures();
    cel=sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);
    Serial.print("Temperatures: ");
    Serial.print(cel);
    Serial.println("");

    tsLastReport=millis();
  }
}

void main_display()
{
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print(F("Temp: "));
    lcd.setCursor(6, 0);
    lcd.print(cel);
    lcd.print((char)223);
    lcd.print('C');
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("SpO2: ");
    lcd.setCursor(6 ,1);
    lcd.print(oxy_lvl);
    delay(200);
}

void send_parameters()
{
  esp8266.listen();
  esp8266.flush();
  esp8266.print(send_data_string);
  delay(5000);  
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print(F("  Uploaded To "));
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print(F("  Firebase  "));
  delay(200);
  esp8266.end();
}

void help_display()
{
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print(F(" PATIENT NEEDS  "));
    lcd.setCursor(6, 1);
    lcd.print(F("HELP      "));
}

void process()
{   
   if((sys > sys_u) || (dia > dia_u))
   {
       system_alert = 1; 
   }
   else if((p < pulse_l ) || (p > pulse_u))
   {
       system_alert = 2; 
   }  
   else if((cel < temp_l ) || (cel > temp_u))
   {
       system_alert = 3; 
   }
   else
   {
       system_alert = 0; 
   }
   delay(200);
}

void alerting()
{
  if(system_alert==1)
   {
    lcd.clear();
    digitalWrite(buzz,HIGH);
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Patient BP");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("Fluctuating");
    delay(3500);
   }
   else if(system_alert==2)
   {
    lcd.clear();
    digitalWrite(buzz,HIGH);
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Patient Pulse");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("Fluctuating");
    delay(3500);
   }
   else if(system_alert==3)
   {
    lcd.clear();
    digitalWrite(buzz,HIGH);
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Temperature");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("Fluctuating");
    delay(3500);
   }
   else
   {
    Serial.print("Continue Monitoring");
    delay(3500);
   }
}
```

Also attaching the code I wrote for integration of the MAX30100 Oximeter and the DS18B20 Thermal Probe standalone below.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "MAX30100_PulseOximeter.h"
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

#define REPORTING_PERIOD_MS     1000
PulseOximeter pox;
uint32_t tsLastReport = 0;
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);

#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 5
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);
float cel=0.00;

// Callback (registered below) fired when a pulse is detected
void onBeatDetected()
{
  Serial.println("Beat!");
}
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("Initializing...");
  sensors.begin();
  sensors.setWaitForConversion(false);
  // Initialize the PulseOximeter instance
  if (!pox.begin()) {
    Serial.println("MAX30100 was not found. Please check the wiring/power.");
    lcd.print("FAILED");
    for (;;);
  } else {
    Serial.println("SUCCESS");
  }
  // pox.setIRLedCurrent(MAX30100_LED_CURR_7_6MA);
  // Register a callback for the beat detection
  pox.setOnBeatDetectedCallback(onBeatDetected);
}
void loop()
{
  float HeartRate = 3.0, SpO2 = 3.0;
  pox.update();
  HeartRate = pox.getHeartRate();
  SpO2 = pox.getSpO2();
  if (millis() - tsLastReport > REPORTING_PERIOD_MS) {
    Serial.print("Heart rate:");
    Serial.print(HeartRate);
    Serial.print("bpm / SpO2:");
    Serial.print(SpO2);
    Serial.println("%");
    sensors.requestTemperatures();
    cel=sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);
    Serial.print("Temperature: ");
    Serial.print(cel);
    Serial.println("");
    tsLastReport = millis();

    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    
    lcd.print("HR:");
    lcd.print(HeartRate);
    lcd.print(" bpm");
 
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    
    lcd.print("SpO2:");
    lcd.print(SpO2);
    lcd.print("%");

    lcd.setCursor(11,1);
    lcd.print("T:");
    lcd.print(cel);
  }
}
```

The required output when I run the second code:

```
Heart Rate: 55.38 BPM / SpO2: 96.00%
Temperature: 25.50
Beat!
Heart Rate: 54.07 BPM / SpO2: 95.00%
Temperature: 26.51
Beat!
Heart Rate: 60.38 BPM / SpO2: 97.00%
Temperature: 27.55
Beat!
```

The output I get when I try to integrate all the sensors together:

```
Heart Rate: 0.00 BPM / SpO2: 0.00%
Temperature: 27.50
Heart Rate: 0.00 BPM / SpO2: 0.00%
Temperature: 27.30
Heart Rate: 0.00 BPM / SpO2: 0.00%
Temperature: 27.36
Heart Rate: 0.00 BPM / SpO2: 0.00%
Temperature: 28.05
```

The link for the BP machine: https://www.sunrom.com/566

Comment: please delete the screenshots and add the actual text instead ... format it as code ... some people here cannot view images